# How to find the $n-th$ term of the series $3,7,12,18...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My attempt:

> Let,$$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space S=3+7+12+18+......+t_n$$
>   $$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  S=\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space 3+7+12+18+...t_{n-1}+t_n$$

Subtracting, 
$$0=3+4+5+6+...(t_n-t_{n-1})-t_n$$
$$\implies t_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-3$$
By adding and subtracting $1,2$.
However this gives a negative value of $t_1$. Where is it wrong?

Comment: I've never seen this approach to finding the nth term of a sequence.. I'm curious to see what others have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{n^2+n}2-3=3\iff0=(n+4)(n-3)$

So, your sequence start with $n=3$

Comment: Suppose I have to find the sum $S$ as given in the question. How do I do it then?

Comment: @tatan, Use https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Comment: @tatan:  you did just fine, but note that $3$ is then the third term of your sum because you put $1,2$ in front.  Then the last term is $t_{n+2}$.   If you want to start counting your terms at $1$, you must update your formula to be $\frac {(n+2)(n+3)}2-3$, which works fine.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahhh.... Thanks a lot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$S= 3+7+12+18+...;$

$S= 3 +(3+4) +( 3+4+5) +(3+4+5+6) +...;$

$S= a_1  +a_2 +a_3 +a_4.......+ a_n;$

$a_n =(3+4+5+ ...(n+2));$

$a_n = 2n+(1+2+3...+n)$, or

$a_n= 2n+n(n+1)/2.$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by induction that $a_{n}=3n+\cfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$
Here, you don't have to assume that $n>2$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $n$ consecutive integers, from $3$ and up to $t_n- t_{n-1}$, isn't $\frac{n(n+1)}2$. If you think about which (and how many) integers $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ usually represents the sum of, you will hopefully see what went wrong.

Comment: i did make it $(1+2)+3+...(t_n-t_{n-1})-(1+2)$

Comment: @tatan I know. I'm trying to tell you that that's not $\frac{n(n+1)}2-3$.

Answer (score 0):

The systematic way is to use [Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series) based on 
repeated differences:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
3 & 7 & 12 & 18 & \\
4 & 5 & 6 & \\
1 & 1 & \\
0 & \\
\end{array}
$$
and so
$$
t_n=3 \binom{n-1}{0} + 4 \binom{n-1}{1} + 1 \binom{n-1}{2}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
t_n=\dfrac{n (n + 5)}{2}
$$